# understand table flow

Tags: sql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql

today i got a DB dump to understand table flow structure;
i uploaded dump on mysql. 
there is 3 databases 
1st DB has 10 tables every table has primary key, and some multi key
2nd DB has 3 every table has primary key, and some multi key
3rd DB has 101 every table has primary key, and some multi key

but there is no any foreign key. 
so how can i understand the table data flow .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any relationship defined then you can query to the tables to find common columns/fields which can be used to define relations. Then you can try MySQL Workbench which gives you an option for reverse engineer database:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/
```

It will help you create a database diagram for the selected tables based on the relationships.

Comment: hi abhay , thanks for your reply .. 
but there is no any relationships between  tables.. 
i used mysql workbanch for reverse engineer  .. but that is showing on tables